# Separatley representing arraylist indexes as Strings

Tags: java, arraylist, tostring

So far I have an ArrayList that has the following contents

```
[[2/11, 11/48], [8/35, 35/288], [16/43, 43/288], [75/152, 19/210], [4/5, 5/16], [135/163, 163/1680]]
```

However I need to represent each individual part of this as a String representation such as
the following,

```
{true@2/11, false@9/11}@11/48
```

Where the false @ is the complement of true@, not so sure how to go about getting them seperatly out of the list, for example I tried

```
knowledegeD.get(0)
```

for the first bit but obviously that just returns

```
{{true@[2/11, 11/48]
```

Any idea on how I would go about this?

Comment: couldn't get your point. what relation does exist between `{true@2/11, false@9/11}@11/48` and `[2/11, 11/48]` ?

Comment: It's a list of strings? Could you provide the list declaration and filling?