# For loop getting multiple values

Tags: java, for-loop, arraylist

I have a for loop

```
for (int i = 0; i < knowledgeD.size(); i++ )
        knowledgeD.get(i).get(0);

        for (int k = 0; k < knowledgeD.size(); k++ )
            knowledgeD.get(k).get(1);
```

However I am majorly confused at how I can store all the results of the for loop to one variable I guess?

like say for example i Do this

```
 for (int i = 0; i < knowledgeD.size(); i++ )
        w =knowledgeD.get(i).get(0);

        for (int k = 0; k < knowledgeD.size(); k++ )
            y = knowledgeD.get(k).get(1);
```

then in my toString() i do

```
String s = "{true@" + w + " " +"false@"  + w.complement() + "}" + "@" + this.y;
```

Where complement() is the complement on the w fraction, in this case 9/11.

This gives me

```
 {true@135/163 false@28/163}@163/1680}
```

Which is fantastic, but thats only the last value of the array of arrays

```
[[2/11, 11/48], [8/35, 35/288], [16/43, 43/288], [75/152, 19/210], [4/5, 5/16], [135/163, 163/1680]]
```

If anyone can shed light that would be much appreciated. Basically the @ true and @ false are probability of a coinflip being heads or tails.

Cheers Sim
PS the datatypes for w and y are BigFractions which are basically fractions, this datatype is in another class.

Comment: In your toString() of which class? (Side note: you could then close [your other question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15699445/1225328) :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

Just append the next value to the s like this

```
StringBuilder str="";

for (int i = 0; i < knowledgeD.size(); i++ )
{
        w =knowledgeD.get(i).get(0);
            y = knowledgeD.get(i).get(1);

    str.append("{true@" + w + " " +"false@"  + w.complement() + "}" + "@" + this.y);
     str.append(" ");
}
```

And in your `toString()` method just call
`s=str.toString()`;

Comment: It would be better to use a `StringBuilder` in this case to avoid creation of a new `String` for each append operation.

Comment: @niculare yeah really..I'll edit according to your suggestion

Comment: hmm thanks i think its working let me double check tho  i fixed some stuff up

Comment: nevermind fixed again, just changed it to one for loop thanks

Comment: @Sim Sorry it was my mistake just remove inner for loop.. check my updated answer

Comment: yeah i just thought about that myself, came back to re edit my post! :) cheers